Received Dental Bill From New Owner's After Previous Owner's Said I Owed Nothing- Can they continue to collect
I received some dental procedures from my original dentist back in October 2022.  We have great insurance coverage and I was told that the services were covered by insurance and if for any reason there was a difference the original dental office would waive any excess amount.  At some point in 2023 the original dental office sold to a new owner. The new owner is now billing me $305.88 for the portion not paid by insurance.  I wrote a letter and let the new owner know that the original dental office told me I didn't owe anything and all fees were waived.  Not to mention they are billing well over a year of the original service.  I requested proof that I owed them money by providing proof of my signature at time of service (I never signed anything saying I owed a balance).  Also, this new company is attempting to collect on service "not rendered" by them.  Seems like that should be illegal by FDCPA laws.  In a written letter back to me the new company acknowledged that the original dental office had a policy of writing off any remaining balances after insurance payments, however, their practice does not??  Is this new company in violation of the FDCPA laws for pursing collections on services not rendered by them?  Thank you for your advice.

"Is this new company in violation of the FDCPA laws for pursing collections on services not rendered by them?" is a question about the law, not a request for advice.

What is FDCPA? Please tag the question with the jurisdiction.

FDCPA = Fair Debt Collection Practices Act (a U.S. federal law). Better practice is to spell out all acronyms at least once in a question.


In a written letter back to me the new company acknowledged that the original dental office had a policy of writing off any remaining balances after insurance payments, however, their practice does not??

So reply in writing that their procedures do not concern you since you contracted with the former entity, not them, and your contract remains unchanged by their purchase of the practice. Thank them for acknowledging the contract that you are party to.  Make sure you state that you dispute the charge in its entirety.

Thank you for feedback.
